# Multiple Toggles Almost like Tabs JavaScript/ CSS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to create tabs that function like toggles, but instead only one toggle can be active at one time. The content of the tab also needs to be above the the tabs themselves. The problem is I am using a loop to generate the content as well as the tabs themselves.

I've got a nice javascript code right here that works perfectly fine. I understand this perfectly as well. The only problem is that it obviously doesn't disable other toggles when another one is clicked. Also having one "tab" / "toggle" always active. Code that could probably check the div id with a prefix of "post" and make all div id's with "post" to display:none besides the one that was clicked on. That would be perfect if that could be possible. Another way I could think of this is putting all the generated content into a container, and it simply disables all id's in the container besides the one that was clicked.

If this code can be modified to achieve that, it would be great. This is some very simple code that I understand very clearly. All I need is that it behaves more like tabs where only one can be active at once.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleMeMirror(a){
    var e=document.getElementById(a);
    if(!e) return true;
    if(e.style.display=="none"){
        e.style.display="inline"
    } else {
        e.style.display="none"
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

HTML / PHP

Loop 1 - The Content

```
<?php while ($queryepisodemirrors->have_posts()) : $queryepisodemirrors->the_post(); ?>
        <?php if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'parentIDmirror', true) == $postIDCheck) { ?>

        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" style="display:none;">
                    <center><?php the_title(); ?><br /><br />
                    <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'mirror_embed_code', true); ?>
                    <?php wprp(true);?>
                </center>
        </div>  
        <?php } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Loop 2 - The actual toggles / tabs

```
<?php while ($queryepisodemirrors->have_posts()) : $queryepisodemirrors->the_post(); ?>
        <?php if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'parentIDmirror', true) == $postIDCheck) { ?>
        <div style="float: left; padding: 4px;">
        <center>



        <div class="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" onclick="return toggleMeMirror('post-<?php the_ID(); ?>')" >
            <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 150px; height: 100px;">
                <div style="background: rgb(0, 0, 0) transparent; /* fallback color */ background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); color: white; padding: 2px;">
                    <center>

                        <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'video_provider', true);
                        echo ' Mirror';?>
                    </center>
                </div>
                <img src="<?php echo $thumbnail_src; ?>" width="150px"/>

            </div>
        </div>


        </center>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: please post the html also

Comment: added the HTML / PHP that's relevant.

Comment: only source of html was needed

Comment: It probably would've been better just to post some simple example result HTML that the Javascript you're having problems with should working with instead of two chunks of PHP whose output is largely tangential to the question. Basically, the exact content and styling of the tabs is irrelevant and might as well be "lorem ipsum", if the issue is managing the state of the tabs.

Comment: More information shouldn't hurt.

Comment: @user1952811 that is not more info,php code that you gave is not relevant ,how we know how many times to loop and other logic you use to generate the html.

Comment: I just wanted to show the fact that the content and the tab/toggles are in separate loops. This should make a difference when coding the javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also tagged jquery so I'll just recommend that you include the jquery library and include:

```
$('.someclass').hide();
```

as the first line in the toggleMeMirror function.

Then, make sure that each of your looped content divs exist in the class "someclass".

like:

```
foreach($this as $that) {
    print "<div class='someclass'>$that</div>";
}
```

then

```
function toggleMeMirror(a){
    // hide all
    $('.someclass').hide();
    //  show one
    var e=document.getElementById(a);
    if(!e) return true;
        if(e.style.display=="none"){
            e.style.display="inline"
        } else {
            e.style.display="none"
        }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. But I seem to receive an error when I try to put this code in. 

This is the error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function 
toggleMeMirror 
onclick

This is how I put the class in: http://pastebin.com/Q4ADkARD

And this is the java script code 

http://pastebin.com/LgDXHTrA

Comment: @user1952811: Drew has assumed that you are already using jQuery, because you tagged your question `jquery`. Without that, there is no `$`. He did indicate this in the first line of his answer, and you ignored it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit

I didn't ignore it. But I am using wordpress, and I believe wordpress calls jQuery in all it's header files when it's creating the page.

I didn't know it was a jQuery error. So this error means that jQuery library hasn't been included onto the page? Right, or could this error mean something else?

Comment: @user1952811: Well it _could_ mean something else, but `$` is the core jQuery function and the error is telling you that it does not exist, so that's pretty clear-cut. Did you do `View Source` in your web browser to see the resulting HTML and find the `<script>` tags to check?

Comment: (It's also possible that Wordpress disables `$` for reasons of conflict resolution, and requires the use of [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), instead.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit so what should I replace "$" with? or should I try to call the jQuery library in the file that I am putting this code into? It's a php file.

Comment: Try writing `jQuery` instead of `$`, as I said in my previous comment and linked you to all the documentation on the subject.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thank you for being so patient with me. I was able to get rid of the error. However, after I wrapped the tabs in the div class. Once I clicked on one tab, all the tabs would be hidden, and it's appropriate content would display. Then I tried to wrap the whole content + tabs into the class. That made it stopped working. I wrapped the content only with the class, and that didn't work either. The content, the tabs that are generated are in separate loops. I wonder if I would need to probably work with two different classes? One that is for tabs and the other for content?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/rQSDz/13/)**

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="one"><img src='http://img.widgetbox.com/thumbs/302/8fb0669c-72ee-454d-a08f-9700b8a5270a.png?4' height='50px' widht='50px' ></div><br>
<div id="two"><img src='http://ww2.valdosta.edu/~mecarter/Spongebob%20Reading.png' height='50px' widht='50px' ></div><br>
<div id="three"><img src='http://www.cliffdweller.com/blogPhotos/wrappingpaperbase/Spongebob%20Waving.png' height='50px' widht='50px' ></div><br><br>
<div id="thumb"><img src='http://img.widgetbox.com/thumbs/302/8fb0669c-72ee-454d-a08f-9700b8a5270a.png?4' height='200px' widht='200px' ></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#one").click(function() {
  $("#thumb").html("<img src='http://img.widgetbox.com/thumbs/302/8fb0669c-72ee-454d-a08f-9700b8a5270a.png?4' height='200px' widht='200px' >");
});

$("#two").click(function() {
  $("#thumb").html("<img src='http://ww2.valdosta.edu/~mecarter/Spongebob%20Reading.png' height='200px' widht='200px' >");
 });

$("#three").click(function() {
   $("#thumb").html("<img src='http://www.cliffdweller.com/blogPhotos/wrappingpaperbase/Spongebob%20Waving.png' height='200px' widht='200px' >");
});
```