# Making Tabs in Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple Toggles Almost like Tabs JavaScript/ CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289925/multiple-toggles-almost-like-tabs-javascript-css)

I am looking for tabs that are made in javascript or jquery whichever one that is easier to implement straight into the html document, the code itself. I don't really need CSS, I just need some markup on how to implement it into my content.

This is the situation. I have thumbnail like images that act as the "tabs" themselves, while I have the content on top of them so it looks somewhat like this...

> ```
>      Dynamic Content Here
> ```

```
thumbnail1  thumbnail2  thumbnail3
```

The dynamic content of course changes depending on the thumbnail that's clicked. I only want one thumbnail's content to be active at one time. Meaning, all the other content must be hidden while one content is active.

Furthermore I am generating these in a loop such as this

```
while some condition in php
```

> > contentGenerated
> >
> > thumbnail associated with the content generated

This loop runs a couple of thumbnails and has associated content with that specific thumbnail. So that's how I determine which content will appear when the thumbnail is clicked.

The first thumbnail and it's content should automatically be active and displayed, like normal tabs. The only difference I see is that the tabs (in my case thumbnails) are located at the bottom, and the content is at the top.

Another problem I was having with other solutions is implementing the markup into the loop. Markup as simple as this would be extremely easy for me to implement...

```
<div class="tabs">
while some condition in php 

<div class="content" id="<?php adynamicIDgenerated ?>">
```

> > contentGenerated

```
</div>

<div class="tab" id="<?php thesameexactID so it can be matched; ?>">
```

> > thumbnail associated with the content generated

```
</div>

</div>
```

Of course the div statements in the loop would be generated for each and every tab. They would have their own ID. Basically the content generated with the thumbnail could easily be matched with having the same ID. I was able to create a toggle with it. I am having problems creating tabs with those specifications.

Comment: Don't keep asking the same question. You have gotten decent answers on your other questions.  Just because they are not "easy" doesn't mean they aren't correct.

Comment: They are pretty easy to implement. They just haven't worked for me. The one that you linked me to had the perfect answer, but the author didn't respond to one of my questions. I tried to fiddle with the answer and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @user1952811: Then offer a bounty. Improve the question through editing. Do not repost.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT UPDATE you can use this with Loops and Php as follows**

```
for($i=1 ; $i < num; $i++)
{
  echo("<div id='".$i."'><img src='img-source.jpg' height='50px' widht='50px' id='thumbnail' ></div><br>");
}

<div id="thumb"><img src='Default.jpg' height='200px' widht='200px' ></div>

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script>

   $("#thumbnail").click(function() {
var imgsrc = $("img#thumbnail").attr("src");
   $("#thumb").html("<img src='"+imgsrc+"' height='200px' widht='200px' >");
     });

 </script>
```

You can try something like this **[DEMO](http://bloggerplugnplay.blogspot.in/2013/01/change-image-with-click-on-tabs-or.html)**

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="one"><img src='http://img.widgetbox.com/thumbs/302/8fb0669c-72ee-454d-a08f-9700b8a5270a.png?4' height='50px' widht='50px' ></div><br>
<div id="two"><img src='http://ww2.valdosta.edu/~mecarter/Spongebob%20Reading.png' height='50px' widht='50px' ></div><br>
<div id="three"><img src='http://www.cliffdweller.com/blogPhotos/wrappingpaperbase/Spongebob%20Waving.png' height='50px' widht='50px' ></div><br><br>
<div id="thumb"><img src='http://img.widgetbox.com/thumbs/302/8fb0669c-72ee-454d-a08f-9700b8a5270a.png?4' height='200px' widht='200px' ></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#one").click(function() {
  $("#thumb").html("<img src='http://img.widgetbox.com/thumbs/302/8fb0669c-72ee-454d-a08f-9700b8a5270a.png?4' height='200px' widht='200px' >");
});

$("#two").click(function() {
  $("#thumb").html("<img src='http://ww2.valdosta.edu/~mecarter/Spongebob%20Reading.png' height='200px' widht='200px' >");
 });

$("#three").click(function() {
   $("#thumb").html("<img src='http://www.cliffdweller.com/blogPhotos/wrappingpaperbase/Spongebob%20Waving.png' height='200px' widht='200px' >");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this can't be hard coded, cause the content is generated in the loop. Meaning I could have 2 thumbnails, or 10.

Also, as stated in my initial question. I need a thumbnail that points to it's own content. Each thumbnail has it's own content that it is attached to. This is also found and explained in my question. I even provide a very basic and incomplete algorithm of the markup that could work with what I want.

Comment: @user1952811 you can modify this code according to your need .We can easily apply loops in this code

Comment: I am inexperienced with jQuery and have no clue as to how to run loops within it. Also, I will have custom generated IDs, and they won't be under my control. So hard coding IDs in won't work.

Comment: @user1952811 try now I have updated the code with loops

Comment: It's not the PHP that I have a problem with. I am having a problem with the actual jQuery code. If you look at my question, you can see that each thumbnail needs to be attached to it's own content. Here is an example here: http://phanime.net/22974/subbed-sword-online-online-episode-1/

Instead of it toggling. I want it so only one content is open at all times. So the other ones are automatically hidden.